# how to remove gap between grid layout when we try to make the while grid fit to screen in angular using css - grid?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-grid

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Booking</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div *ngFor="let parking of parkings; let i=index; let x=index;">
        <div class="grid-item">{{parking.column}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(38, 60px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0px, auto);
}

.grid-item {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #00ff73;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import parkingData from "./layout.json";
interface Parking {
  row: String;
  value: String;
  column: String;
  number: String;
  direction: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  parkings: Parking[] = parkingData;
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

current output:
[image]

how to make the above grid container fit to screen size when ever we do (ctrl + scroll)

when i add the CSS change width and height to fit the screen:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(38, 60px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0px, auto);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-item {
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #00ff73;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

I get output like this:
[image]

**What should i do to over come this issue in order to make it fit to the screen.**
**NOTE: the number of columns should not wrap the number of row and columns(row and column count should remain the same)**

LINK TO CODESANDBOX - https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-layout-demo-3tvuhg

Comment: align-content: start

Comment: OR replace auto with 1fr

Comment: didn't work. nothing happened

Comment: kindly check the sandbox for working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-layout-demo-3tvuhg

Comment: Your grid-item is not a direct-child of the grid container. try : `.grid-container>*{/*styles*/}` instead  `.grid-item{/*styles*/}` or move the grid-item class to `<div *ngFor="let parking of parkings; let i=index; let x=index;">` . ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I tried them both. didn't work. can you check the sandbox. it's editable.  [link] https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-layout-demo-3tvuhg  i want the whole layout to fit to screen. i shouldn't scroll to see the rest of the layout.

Comment: remove all of your `align-` rules, so the children will just fill the row they are in.